# R Stuck in Debug Mode with Apply

Tags: r

I was debugging a function I had written that was being called by apply.  I got the function to work, but now am stuck in debug mode with approximately 2000 more iterations to get out.  Is there a way to "break" (like break out of a for loop) for an apply function?

Minimum working example where I don't want to press 'c' every time func is called:

```
func <- function(z) {
 browser()
 return(z)
}
x <- runif(2000)
result <- apply(x, FUN=func)
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Use `debugonce` instead of `browser` ?

Comment: Yes, I understand that I could have done something else to not have this problem, but I am currently stuck in this situation.

Comment: Oh, I see, you want an equivalent of `n` but for `apply`. I don't think you can do that without explicitly debugging more functions, i.e. you'd need to debug in `apply`.

Comment: You're not "stuck" : just kill off the current debug session and start the function up again.

Comment: You should just be able to type `Q` (capitalized) and hit `Enter` to return to the command line, no? This works in my R session.